# Create a circle and each border have their own text?

Tags: html, css

**Note: I am not using any SVG.**

I have a circle and each border has there owned text and color.

Note: I am not using any plugin. It's just a static circle with text.

It is possible to make this using HTML and CSS? If Yes then please give me some hit from where to start this.

[image]

```css
.circle-donut{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 140px solid #52e291;
  border-bottom: 140px solid #3400fe;
  border-right: 140px solid #ff7d36;
  border-left: 140px solid #faff08;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-donut"></div>
```

**With position absolute**

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.circle-donut {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 140px solid #a3fe01;
  border-bottom: 140px solid #2800eb;
  border-right: 140px solid #dd6479;
  border-left: 140px solid #ead52c;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
}

ul li {
  position: absolute;
}

ul li.top {
  top: 0;
}

ul li.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

ul li.left {
  left: 0;
}

ul li.right {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circle-donut">

  </div>

  <ul>
    <li class="top">Come content one</li>
    <li class="right">Come content Two</li>
    <li class="bottom">Come content Three</li>
    <li class="left">Come content Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You do pretty well. :)

Comment: If the page is static and you *only* want to create this, then it can be done with position absolute elements

Comment: @RayeesAC, I have to display the text also. So where I have to add text?

Comment: Add text by absolute positioning to achieve this.

Comment: My question if a little bit different, I don't want to use any SVG. I just want to circle along with text

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, I added one more example in the question with absolute

Comment: Ahh, I was busy with my answer. another way would be to create each piece of the circle and assign it to a div and then you can add text within the div and have a bit more control over your text (responsive, add different fonts, etc) this way doesn't matter, where your circle is the text of each piece, will be correctly aligned. And you can then assign some sweet on hover effects on each piece